# Special series in R

Tags: r

I would like to compute the following expression in R. It includes two series and one product. I know how to create the second series. The following code is regarded to the second series.

```
    x=runif(10, 0.1,5)
    ak=sum(x[1:(j-1)])
    aq=sum(x[1:j])
```

I think we can use `cumprod` for producing the product, but I do not know how I can combine it with a `for` loop to get the result in R.

[image]

Comment: Your expression is ill-defined: missing a closing parenthesis, nowhere uses the `j` index, ... Also, if you're writing latex, we shouldn't see `^`s like that for exponentiation.

Comment: Just curious if you really mean `1:j-1` or if you want `1:(j - 1)`? And I too would expect `j` to appear in your equation *somewhere* other than in the product index.

Comment: Try generating the sequence of `exp(...)` over all `i` in a `for` loop or use `sapply` and then call `cumprod` on this. Then multiply with `x` and `sum`.